# Ansible copy a file that must be read-only and owned by another user

Tags: ansible, copy, file-permissions

I need to copy a file (a munge key in this case) from a control node to multiple slave nodes, and I'd like to use ansible copy to do so. The problem is that this file must be owned by the munge user and have owner-read-only permissions, '0400'. The directory it's in must be owned by munge and have permissions '0700'.

The ansible task structure below works for other files with more permissive '0644' permissions, and even sets owner/group/permissions successfully, but fails for this file:

```
- name: Copy munge key
  copy:
    src: /etc/munge/munge.key
    dest: /etc/munge/munge.key
    owner: munge
    group: munge
    mode: '0400'
```

Is there a way to 'become root or munge' both locally and remotely to copy the file? Or is there another simple solution to this problem?

EDIT:

I have tried `become: yes`, with `become_user: root` and separately with `become_user: munge`. Neither worked. It fails with the error `"Could not find or access '/etc/munge/munge.key'"` each time. The file is there, but both /etc/munge and /etc/munge/munge.key have permissions only for the munge user.

EDIT 2:

My hackish long-winded solution consists of five tasks that 1. Free up permissions on the source file and directory; 2. Free up permissions on remote file and directory; 3. Copy the file; 4. Lock up remote file and directory permissions; 5. Lock up original source file and directory. This works, but I'm still confused about when, exactly 'become' takes effect and whether it takes effect only on the source node or also on the remote node and how that may cause my one-step copy to fail.

Answer (score -1):

Add:

```
become: true
```

That should be enough to avoid task failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @sorin. I added edits to clarify that this isn't fixing the problem. Perhaps it needs to 'become' both locally and remotely; I don't know.

Comment: you may need to also add become_user: root

Comment: On selinux enabled systems you may also need selinux module, but ansible will tell you if it needs it.